# How to install JXcore with Visual Studio and Cordova

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2015, jxcore

I am working on a small project, and I am new to Cordova. I am reusing some old scripts I made for use with Node.JS but Cordova is missing many of the functions they require. I read about is and learned JXcore may be the solution to this problem, however I cannot comprehend the installation directions. I was hoping someone could dumb it down for me. I plan on releasing this application on Windows and Android, if that is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the instructions on jxcore-cordova repository. **It has been just updated** for Visual Studio installation.

https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore-cordova#visual-studio

Comment: I got it to install but I'm am still getting 'require is not defined' error. I may be mistaken but I thought JXcore added it. Am I doing something wrong? Here is my project file if you would like to look. https://www.dropbox.com/s/praxm2e3jegrn2z/Cheese%20Bot.zip?dl=0

Comment: Are you receiving this during app build or app run? I'll look into the project. (you may also post the issue on https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore-cordova/issues)

Comment: I think I found the issue. I wasn't running the script using JXcore. I was still using the built in function. However I am still having a few problems, I do not think it relates to JXcore. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use your nodejs libraries in phone using JXcore cordova plugin. It's easy to create sample JXcore cordova project this way:

1. [Download and install JXcore](https://jxcore.s3.amazonaws.com/0307/jx_winsetup.zip) (For windows)
2. Run `install_and_run.bat`. You can find it [here](https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore-cordova/blob/master/install_and_run.bat).

This bash script automates installation process. First it creates sample cordova project, then downloads and adds JXcore cordova plugin, adds platforms to project and finally runs app.